# Apollo GraphQL client: how to distinguish an optimistic response from a real response into a watchQuery

Tags: apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

The question is about the interaction of a mutation, optimistic response, and a watchQuery.

I have a mutation "myMutation" which has an "optimisticResponse" and an implemented "update" function.

Every time I do a mutation query the "update" function is called twice, the first time with optimistic response data and the second one with real data. All is Ok and all as described in the documentation.

Into my "update" function I modify "myQuery" cache data through using readQuery/writeQuery methods.

Every time I modify "myQuery" cache data a watchQuery (based on "myQuery") subscription is called. All is Ok and all as described in the documentation.

But the problem is that I cannot distinguish into my watchQuery whether I receive optimistic response data or real response data. It is crucial for me because the reaction must be different since valuable part of data can be provided by a server only.
I should show a GUI element with a special style when I receive an optimistic response and I should prohibit any interactions with it until I receive a real response.

Unfortunately, I can't solve this matter. At a glance, there is no difference between optimistic and real responses. I've googled a lot and haven't found a solution. The only idea I have is adding a special field to my GraphQL data which will show whether a response is received from a server or not. But it looks ugly and smells bad. I am sure, there must be a simple correct way to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe there is an easier way or there will be one in the future but here is what I know.

The data in `optimisticResponse` is only provided during the first call to update. That is where you can flag to your update function that it is dealing with optimistic data. You can put any data you want there. I put `isOptimistic: true,`.

To deal with the `watchQuery` issue, I recommend you make use of `apollo-link-state` to add a client-only field or fields to the areas of your data model where optimistic upserts should be known to the display. Don't include `isOptimistic` in your mutation query so you know it's from the server and not the optimistic response and force it to false if it's not true. See this example:

```js
const SUBMIT_COMMENT_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation submitComment($repoFullName: String!, $commentContent: String!) {
    submitComment(repoFullName: $repoFullName, commentContent: $commentContent) {
      postedBy {
        login
        html_url
      }
      createdAt
      content
    }
  }
`;

const CommentsPageWithMutations = ({ currentUser }) => (
  <Mutation mutation={SUBMIT_COMMENT_MUTATION}>
    {(mutate) => (
      <CommentsPage
        submit={(repoFullName, commentContent) =>
          mutate({
            variables: { repoFullName, commentContent },
            optimisticResponse: {
              __typename: 'Mutation',
              submitComment: {
                __typename: 'Comment',
                postedBy: currentUser,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                content: commentContent,
                isOptimistic: true, // Only provided to update on the optimistic call
              },
            },
            update: (proxy, { data: { submitComment } }) => {
              // Make sure CommentAppQuery includes isOptimistic for each comment added by apollo-link-state
              // submitComment.isOptimistic will be undefined here if it's from the server
              const newComment = {
                ...submitComment,
                isOptimistic: submitCommit.isOptimistic ? true : false,
              };

              // Read the data from our cache for this query.
              const data = proxy.readQuery({ query: CommentAppQuery });

              // Add our comment from the mutation to the end.
              data.comments.push(newComment);

              // Write our data back to the cache.
              proxy.writeQuery({ query: CommentAppQuery, data });
            },
          })
        }
      />
    )}
  </Mutation>
);
```

See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately, another problem occurred. Then I use apollo-link-state mutation and watchQuery work properly. But if a client-only field exists also in a subscription it suddenly stops after the first response is received. I use a default:  

Sorry, I do not understand why a code block doesn't work.  

<code>
    const defaultState = {
        _loadingStatus: 'READY'
    };
    const stateLink = withClientState({
        cache,
        defaults: defaultState,
        resolvers: {}
    });
</code>
which I change in my optimistic response.

Comment: @Dolios There's a lot going on with your issue I cannot see. However, you said it stops working after the client-only field is added to the subscription. Could you try to not have it in the subscription and then just read that value from cache within your subscribe logic? It may be a bug in the subscription logic with link-state. I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It looks like a bug in `apollo-link-state`. I created an issue on this matter:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/249

Comment: To make this solution work with Apollo 3 see the answer below by Francois Nadeau

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work on Apollo 3.X by only adding a property on the optimistic response, the property was getting stripped away. To get it to work I had to add a local variable to the query.

```
fragment object on Object {
    id
    isOptimistic @client
...
```

Once that is done, I was able to add the local-only flag to my optimistic response.

```
const optimisticResponse = {
   object: {
    id: "temp-id",
    isOptimistic: true,
    ...
   }
}
```